# How do I ungroup an ROBLOX characters limbs?

Tags: modeling, mesh

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7uTBcDtstKo&feature=youtu.be

Video of my problemo

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: it looks like it's one unique object? Go in Edit mode (tab), select the part you want hovering over one vertex and pressing L, and press P (Separate) > Selection (or select all and press P (Separate) > By Loose Parts)

Comment: Thank you very much, I tested it and was able to ungroup all the parts, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Technically it's not a "group", it's an object, and an object can count several separate meshes.

To separate one or several meshes from the object into one or several new distinct objects:

Go in Edit mode (<kbd>tab</kbd>), select the part you want hovering over one vertex and pressing <kbd>L</kbd>, and press <kbd>P</kbd> *(Separate)* > *Selection* (or select all and press <kbd>P</kbd> *(Separate)* > *By Loose Parts*)